# Почему внутренние классы не могут определять static переменные?

Tags: java

Мне интересно почему компилятор выдает ошибку при попытке объявить статистическую переменную во внутреннем классе?

```
public class Example {

class InnerClass {
static int Index = 1;
 } 
}
```

ошибка:

```
static int Index = 1;
           ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow привел

Comment: Потому, что InnerClass должен быть static.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Потому что внутренние классы ассоциированы с экземпляром внешнего класса (в данном случае `Example`), что соответственно накладывает ограничения и в том числе невозможность объявления статических переменных.

Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members
>   itself.

Вы можете объявить внутренний класс статическим, либо сделать статическую переменную константой.

Также из [спецификации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> Inner classes may not declare static initializers (§8.7) or member
>   interfaces, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant
>   variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Inner classes may inherit static members that are not constant
>   variables even though they may not declare them.
>
> Nested classes that are not inner classes may declare static members
>   freely, in accordance with the usual rules of the Java programming
>   language. Member interfaces (§8.5) are implicitly static so they are
>   never considered to be inner classes.

Comment: Добавлю только, что объявляя внутренний класс статическим, мы получим возможность создания объекта этого класса без предварительного создания объекта родительского класса.